# What alternatives to 'find' are there which will work in a cron environment in the rackspace cloud?

Tags: cron, rackspace-cloud

I am writing a shell script to run a mysql backup as a cron job and am hitting an issue with the find command not being supported in the rackspace cloud sites cron environment. Any attempt to use the find command gives: /usr/bin/find: Permission denied

What alternatives are there to doing:

```
find *.gz -mtime +7 -delete
```

when the files are named like this :

```
gzip > /mnt/target03/rest-of-path/web/backups/DATABASENAME_`date "+%Y-%m-%d"`.gz
```

?

I was hoping that I could parse the file's date without using find in a loop, something like:

```
FILES=./path/to/files/*
for f in $FILES
do
 #delete files older than 7 days without using find

done
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean about it not being supported? Is it not installed?

Comment: Try, /usr/bin/find path -name '*.gz' -mtime +7 -delete.  Try setting your PATH in the script or using the full path.

Comment: Is that a RedHat system? If not, which distro?

Comment: By not supported I mean that the the cron user does not have permission to use the find command. I have updated the question.

Comment: Cloud sites is built on RedHat Enterprise server

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest uploading your own copy of find if it doesn't exist there.

If that doesn't work, a Perl script using the [File::Find](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html) module might be useful.

Comment: I will have to do it in PHP as I don't know perl but I'm guessing some kind of directory iteration and deletion is probably what I will end up doing.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a PATH environment issue.  As a commenter mentioned, you may want to try the full path in your cron.

Try

```
whereis find
which find
locate find
```

To see if you can identify the full path to find.

On Red Hat systems, find is part of the findutils RPM and typically located at:

/usr/bin/find

so rewrite your cron as:

```
/usr/bin/find *.gz -mtime +7 -delete
```

Comment: I have been told by rackspace that I simply will not have permission to run the find command. I have updated my question with the relevant error.