# Using AutoMySQLBackup on Rackspace Cloud

Tags: cron, mysql, rackspace-cloud

Since Rackspace Cloud only allows FTP access it makes using AutoMySQLBackup a little trickier, and while it is at least creating DB dumps I get errors in the backup log:

```
###### WARNING ######
Errors reported during AutoMySQLBackup execution.. Backup failed
Error log below..
.../backups/automysqlbackup: line 1791: /usr/bin/find: Permission denied
.../backups/automysqlbackup: line 1855: /usr/bin/find: Permission denied
.../backups/automysqlbackup: line 803: /usr/bin/find: Permission denied
.../backups/automysqlbackup: line 1972: /usr/bin/du: Permission denied
```

Since files are being created I'm assuming the find command failing has to do with actually rotating out and deleting the old backups?

Line 803:

```
find "${CONFIG_backup_dir}/${subfolder}${subsubfolder}" -mtime 
+"${rotation}" -type f -exec rm {} \;
```

Any ideas for alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as noted [elsewhere](https://serverfault.com/questions/342809/what-alternatives-to-find-are-there-which-will-work-in-a-cron-environment-in-t), Rackspace Cloud doesn't allow access to the find command. Perhaps some kind of security concern? In any case I ended up building on someone else's bash script which versions daily/weekly/monthly backups without the find command:

```
#!/bin/bash
####################################
#
# Purpose:  Create daily, weekly and monthly rotating backups
#           (Originally for WordPress web content and MySQL DB
#           on Rackspace Cloud Sites)
#
#####################################

##### SETTINGS #####
BACKUP_NAME="SOMEWEBSITE Web & DB Backup"                               # What is the name of this backup?
BACKUP_SITEROOT=""                                                      # Root directory of website
BACKUP_TARGET=$BACKUP_SITEROOT"/backups"                                # Where to store the backups
BACKUP_FILES=$BACKUP_SITEROOT"/web/content"                             # What directories to backup

# Database info
DB_USER=""
DB_PASS=""
DB_HOST=""
DB_NAME=""

# How many weekly backups and monthly backups to save
WEEKS_TO_SAVE=4     # default: 4
MONTHS_TO_SAVE=6    # default: 6

# Which day of the week and month to version backups on
BACKUP_DAYOFWEEK="Saturday"  # default: "Saturday"
BACKUP_DAYOFMONTH=1          # default: 1

# Archive file names
ARCHIVE_DB="db_backup_"`date +%Y-%m-%d`
ARCHIVE_WEB="web_backup_"`date +%Y-%m-%d`.tar.bz2

/bin/echo "======================================================================"
/bin/echo "Starting Backup Task:" $BACKUP_NAME
/bin/echo "======================================================================"

# CREATE DAILY BACKUP
/bin/echo "Creating daily backup archives..."

# Check to make sure the folders exist, if not create them.
/bin/mkdir -p $BACKUP_TARGET/daily.{0..6}

# Delete the oldest backup folder.
/bin/rm -rf $BACKUP_TARGET/daily.7

# Shift all the backup folders up a day.
for i in $(eval echo {7..1})
 do
    /bin/mv $BACKUP_TARGET/daily.$[${i}-1] $BACKUP_TARGET/daily.${i}
 done

# Create tar'ed and bzip2 archive of web content
tar cfj $BACKUP_TARGET/daily.1/$ARCHIVE_WEB $BACKUP_FILES

# Dump MySQL DB and create bzip2 archive
mysqldump --opt -h $DB_HOST -u $DB_USER -p$DB_PASS $DB_NAME > $BACKUP_TARGET/daily.1/$ARCHIVE_DB.sql
bzip2 $BACKUP_TARGET/daily.1/$ARCHIVE_DB.sql

# CREATE WEEKLY BACKUP
DAYOFWEEK=$(date +%A)
if [ $DAYOFWEEK == $BACKUP_DAYOFWEEK ]
then
    /bin/echo "It's" $DAYOFWEEK"! Copying latest Daily backups to Weekly..."

    # Check to make sure the folders exist, if not create them.
    eval "/bin/mkdir -p $BACKUP_TARGET/weekly.{0..$WEEKS_TO_SAVE}"

    # Delete the oldest backup folder.
    /bin/rm -rf $BACKUP_TARGET/weekly.$WEEKS_TO_SAVE

    # Shift all the backup folders up a day.
    for i in $(eval echo {$WEEKS_TO_SAVE..1})
     do
        /bin/mv $BACKUP_TARGET/weekly.$[${i}-1] $BACKUP_TARGET/weekly.${i}
     done

    # Copy archives to weekly
    /bin/cp $BACKUP_TARGET/daily.1/* $BACKUP_TARGET/weekly.1/
else
    /bin/echo "Skipping Weekly archive creation until" $BACKUP_DAYOFWEEK
fi

# CREATE MONTHLY BACKUP 
DAYOFMONTH=$(date +%d)
if [ $DAYOFMONTH -eq $BACKUP_DAYOFMONTH ]
then
    /bin/echo "It's the" $DAYOFMONTH"st! Copying latest Daily backups to Monthly..."

    eval "/bin/mkdir -p $BACKUP_TARGET/monthly.{0..$MONTHS_TO_SAVE}"

    # Delete the oldest backup folder.
    /bin/rm -rf $BACKUP_TARGET/monthly.$MONTHS_TO_SAVE

    # Shift all the backup folders up a day.
    for i in $(eval echo {$MONTHS_TO_SAVE..1})
     do
        /bin/mv $BACKUP_TARGET/monthly.$[${i}-1] $BACKUP_TARGET/monthly.${i}
     done

    # Copy archives to monthly
    /bin/cp $BACKUP_TARGET/daily.1/* $BACKUP_TARGET/monthly.1/
else
    /bin/echo "Skipping Monthly archive creation until the" $BACKUP_DAYOFMONTH"st"
fi

/bin/echo "======================================================================"
/bin/echo "Completed Backup Task:" $BACKUP_NAME
/bin/echo "======================================================================"
```